# svelte conditionnal class with a tailwind class including a slash in its name

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte

I use tailwind in a sveltejs project.

Some tailwind classes have a slash in their name,
not compatible with svelte conditionnal classes.

Example:

```html
<div class:w-1/3={condition}>
```

there is an error on the `3` : `Expected >svelte(unexpected-token)`

**How is it possible to use tailwind classes with a slash in their name in a svletejs conditionnal class?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no way of escaping characters documented. I would recommend just using the regular `class` attribute instead, it is equivalent to:

```html
<div class={condition ? 'w-1/3' : ''}>
```

(Additional code is required if other code also wants to set `class`, e.g. as a prop/rest prop.)

Comment: **`/` is a valid character in class names.** The CSS specification defines that non-ASCII characters are valid: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#ident-token-diagram

It’s svelte, that doesn’t support valid class names.

Comment: @MaxHoffmann: It's not valid, because *it is* ASCII but not a letter, underscore or dash.

Comment: Not if it’s escaped and therefore a Unicode code point as defined in the specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#escaping

It’s in the spec, all browsers support it and that’s also the reason why Tailwind is able to use slashes in class names. It’s Svelte’s compiler that cannot handle it in the directive. Your example is the best proof that it works as soon as one doesn’t use Svelte’s proprietary syntax.

Comment: Also adding Matthias Bynens fantastic page here that demonstrates lots of valid class names, including using emojis:

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/crazy-class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tailwind, you can also use the [@apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) directive and a custom class :

```html
<div class:custom-class>
```

```css
.custom-class {
  @apply w-1/3;
}
```